# Perl Int Function Is Not Casting Properly, Decrementing

Tags: perl, casting, int

Problem:  I want to round a number down to the nearest .01.

This is the solution I came up with:

```
return int($_[0]*100)/100;
```

Seems fine until I serendipitously isolated this little gem in the debugger:

```
DB<2> p $_[0]
16.78
DB<3> p $_[0] * 100
1678
DB<4> p int($_[0] * 100)
1677
DB<5> p int(16.78 * 100)
1678
```

One important note is that $_[0] was originally scraped from some text.  It seems like Perl is representing the text "16.78" as 16.78 the number minus some epsilon but printing it as "16.78".

P.S. POSIX::floor fails in the same way.

To dspain:

Ahh but what if the input is 16.7799?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $float = 16.7799;
my $not_rounded     = int($float*100)/100;
my $sprintf_rounded = sprintf "%.2f", $float;
my $int_rounded     = int( ($float+0.005) * 100 )/100;

print "first method: " . $not_rounded ."\n";     # => 16.77
print "second method: " . $sprintf_rounded ."\n"; # => 16.78
print "third method: " . $int_rounded . "\n";     # => 16.78
```

The result should be 16.77, but here they are:

```
$ perl test.pl
first method: 16.77
second method: 16.78
third method: 16.78
```

So, to rephrase, I want to round down to the nearest hundredth but round *up* in the case where the input is as close to an integral multiple of hundredths as can be represented by a floating point number while not exceeding that number of hundredths.

For example, if the input is 16.77999999999999758415 and that is both the most accurate representation of the nearest multiple of 0.01 (16.78) and also less than that number, then round up to the nearest 0.01, else round down to the nearest 0.01.

Note that I am operating under the assumption that when Perl sets a scalar scraped from text that could be interpreted as a floating point decimal, it will choose the most accurate representation it can.  Probably reasonable.

Comment: For enlightenment, execute `printf "%.20f", $_[0]` in the debugger.

Comment: DB<2> printf "%.20f", $_[0]
    16.77999999999999758415

Comment: This is a frequently asked question. [http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Why-is-int()-broken?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Why-is-int%28%29-broken%3F)

Comment: note that sprintf, per POSIX, rounds "in an implementation-defined manner".  for most POSIX systems, this is rounding to nearest, with exactly half rounded to an even final digit.  so it can't be depended on to (and often won't) "round down" if that is what you explicitly want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an idea of the accuracy of the internal floating point representation by printing something that's irrational in binary, like this

```
printf "%.30f\n", 4/9;
```

and I get

```
0.444444444444444420000000000000
```

so my floats are accurate to about sixteen significant figures.

Now you can round to the nearest properly-represented number by adding 5 to the sixteenth digit, so allowing for the two digits before the point,

```
sub trunc {
  my $x = shift() + 5E-14;
  int($x * 100) / 100.0;
}

print trunc(16.77999999999999758415);
```

**output**

```
16.78
```

Of course there is no need to push the limits of the accuracy of Perl's floats: you can simply add half of whatever is the accuracy of your input data and get the right result.

Comment: There we go. It's true that this problem reduces to finding the accuracy of one's internal floating point representation. This is a good way of doing it. I cannot, however, just use half the accuracy of the input data because I want to round down in all cases except when the representation is less than 1 "minimum unit" below the nearest multiple of 0.01

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you have to account for strange artifacts when using floating point arithmetic.  Here's a couple of ways to round that should work instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $float = 16.77999999999999758415
my $not_rounded     = int($float*100)/100;
my $sprintf_rounded = sprintf "%.2f", $float;
my $int_rounded     = int( ($float+0.005) * 100 )/100;

say $not_rounded;     # => 16.77
say $sprintf_rounded; # => 16.78
say $int_rounded;     # => 16.78
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    #!usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    $\ = "\n";
    print "Enter the value and the roundto [Ex:roundto nearest 100 or 1000 etc] ";
    chomp (my $value = <STDIN>);
    chomp (my $digit = <STDIN>);
    my $round;
    $round = int( ($value+ $digit /2)/ $digit )* $digit;
    print "After rounding: $round";
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt Arun.  See the comment in Borodin's response for the reason why this is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one pass at a solution.  Surely there is a superior one out there.

```
sub regex_round_down {
    my $var = shift;
    $var =~ s/^\./0./;
    $var =~ s/^(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?).*$/$1/;
    return $var;
}
```